# What word describes the simple pleasure of using a well-designed tool?

Tags: single-word-requests

The value of most tools is in how they let you accomplish other tasks. After all, a hammer isn't a great tool because it's a hammer, it's a great tool because it lets you affix things to other things quickly (and has a pretty simple interface to do it). Some tools grow to become mired in scope creep and you often spend more time understanding (fighting) the tool than you do solving the problem the tool is meant to solve, which usually leads people to label such tools as "bad".

I'd like to find a word that describes not the elegance/simplicity/utility of the tool itself, but rather the *pleasure* people find in using/discovering "good" tools. This could integrate ideas like discoverability, ease-of-use, availability, robustness, etc.

Comment: [**ergonomics**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ergonomics) is the art/science of trying to *maximise* that "pleasure", but I'm not convinced English has many if any words specifically applicable to the *enjoyment* that people might get from any particular pleasurable activity.

Comment: Werkzeugfreude? Screwfix?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed. This is a notion for which I find no word. The only related but imperfect phrase (which is why I do not post as an answer) I think of it that the tool "comes easily to hand".

Comment: Is the tool an actual physical tool? A software library? An application? Hardware?

Comment: @WeatherVane: ***Screwfix*** comes close - but a ***fix*** is what ***gives*** the addict pleasure, it's not the pleasure itself. But in the same spirit, ***buzzkill*** - the pleasure psychopaths get from carrying out their favourite activity.

Comment: Could you provide a sample sentence, and perhaps some words you considered and reasons you disqualified them?

Comment: Isn't that simple 'satisfaction'?